# Converting augmented matrix to reduced row echelon form

Tags: linear-algebra

I am struggling with reducing an augmented matrix to reduced row echelon form.

The given linear system is \begin{cases}
3x-2z=-3 \\
-2x+z=-2  \\
-z=2 \\
\end{cases}

I can write this as an augmented matrix: 
  \begin{array}{ccc|c}
        3&0&-2&-3\\
        -2&0&1&-2\\
        0&0&-1&2
      \end{array}

But I am unable to get past this to the reduce row echelon form.  I am also supposed to find the solution to the linear system but that isn't making any sense to me either.

Comment: Should it have been\begin{array}{ccc|c}
        3&0&-2&-3\\
        -2&0&1&-2\\
        0&0&0&-2
      \end{array}

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{array}{ccc|c}
3&0&-2&-3\\
-2&0&1&-2\\
0&0&-1&2
\end{array}$$
Multiply the first row by 1/3 to  put a pivot at $1,1$:

$$\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&0&-2/3&-1\\
-2&0&1&-2\\
0&0&-1&2
\end{array}$$

Add 2 times first row to the second row to clear out the pivot column:

$$\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&0&-2/3&-1\\
0&0&-1/3&0\\
0&0&-1&2
\end{array}$$

Multiply the 3rd row by -1 to put a pivot at 3,3:

$$\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&0&-2/3&-1\\
0&0&-1/3&0\\
0&0&1&-2
\end{array}$$

Clear out third pivot column, first add 2/3 of the 3rd row to the first:

$$\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&0&0&-7/3\\
0&0&-1/3&0\\
0&0&1&-2
\end{array}$$

Second, add 1/3 of the third row to the second to finish clearing the pivot column:

$$\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&0&0&-7/3\\
0&0&0&-2/3\\
0&0&1&-2
\end{array}$$

This is the RRE form of your augmented matrix.  Note that your equation never had any solutions from the start, as the RRE indicates on the second row: $0 = -2/3$.  Also note that most teachers will probably think that adding extra rows and columns of zeros to a matrix is a mistake (and it is if you don't know why it is ok).